# Why is 64 bit Delphi app calculating different results than 32 bit build?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, 32bit-64bit

We recently started the process of creating 64 bit builds of our applications. During comparison testing we found that the 64 bit build is calculating differently. I have a code sample that demonstrates the difference between the two builds.

```
var
  currPercent, currGross, currCalcValue : Currency;
begin

  currGross := 1182.42;
  currPercent := 1.45;
  currCalcValue := (currGross * (currPercent * StrToCurr('.01')));
  ShowMessage(CurrToStr(currCalcValue));
end;
```

If you step through this in the 32 bit version, currCalcValue is calculated with 17.1451 while the 64 bit version comes back with 17.145.

Why isn't the 64 bit build calculating out the extra decimal place? All variables are defined as 4 decimal currency values.

Comment: Most likely because of the loss of precision in `Extended` in 64bit. In 32bit, `Extended` is 10 bytes, but in 64bit it is only 8 bytes.  [This is documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Delphi_Considerations_for_Cross-Platform_Applications#The_Extended_Data_Type_Is_2_Bytes_Smaller_on_64-bit_Windows_Systems).

Comment: And if you look at the generated machine code, 32bit and 64bit are doing very different things during your calculations on the third line. 32bit uses floating-point arithmetic, 64bit uses integer arithmetic instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, your first comment is very wide of the mark. The 32 bit compiler gives the same result even in 8 byte precision mode as it does in 10 byte precision mode. Note that there are no floating point calculations performed in the 64 bit version, as your yourself observe.

Comment: If you look at the code David posted, you'll see that 32 bit uses integer arithmetic too, but integer arithmetic performed in the FPU. Currency is, after all, not a floating point type, it is an integer. So in effect, the pieces of code are not doing very different things at all.

Comment: @Rudy Your analysis is incorrect. The 32 bit code performs floating point arithmetic and not integer arithmetic. Note the intermediate value of 171,450.9. Floating point units perform floating point arithmetic. I see two fmulp and an fdiv. Those are floating point arithmetic operations. The two versions are performing very different operations. The truncation of intermediate values is key.

Comment: @David: well indeed, the intermediate result is 80 bit floating point. The intermediate is indeed more accurate. The problem is, of course, the division by 10000 EACH time, instead of only at the end, when that is necessary. Did you report this in QC? I think this could and should be improved.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In this case you would probably be fine with 32 bit floats for the intermediate values. Certainly 64 bit are more than enough. I did not report it to QC. Please feel free to do so.

Comment: I will later on, when I'm at home.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's my SSCCE based on your code. Note the use of a console application. Makes life much simpler.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  currPercent, currGross, currCalcValue : Currency;
begin
  currGross := 1182.42;
  currPercent := 1.45;
  currCalcValue := (currGross * (currPercent * StrToCurr('.01')));
  Writeln(CurrToStr(currCalcValue));
  Readln;
end.
```

Now look at the code that is generated. First 32 bit:

```
Project3.dpr.13: currCalcValue := (currGross * (currPercent * StrToCurr('.01')));
0041C409 8D45EC           lea eax,[ebp-$14]
0041C40C BADCC44100       mov edx,$0041c4dc
0041C411 E8A6A2FEFF       call @UStrLAsg
0041C416 8B1504E74100     mov edx,[$0041e704]
0041C41C 8B45EC           mov eax,[ebp-$14]
0041C41F E870AFFFFF       call StrToCurr
0041C424 DF7DE0           fistp qword ptr [ebp-$20]
0041C427 9B               wait 
0041C428 DF2DD83E4200     fild qword ptr [$00423ed8]
0041C42E DF6DE0           fild qword ptr [ebp-$20]
0041C431 DEC9             fmulp st(1)
0041C433 DF2DE03E4200     fild qword ptr [$00423ee0]
0041C439 DEC9             fmulp st(1)
0041C43B D835E4C44100     fdiv dword ptr [$0041c4e4]
0041C441 DF3DE83E4200     fistp qword ptr [$00423ee8]
0041C447 9B               wait
```

And the 64 bit:

```
Project3.dpr.13: currCalcValue := (currGross * (currPercent * StrToCurr('.01')));
0000000000428A0E 488D4D38         lea rcx,[rbp+$38]
0000000000428A12 488D1513010000   lea rdx,[rel $00000113]
0000000000428A19 E84213FEFF       call @UStrLAsg
0000000000428A1E 488B4D38         mov rcx,[rbp+$38]
0000000000428A22 488B155F480000   mov rdx,[rel $0000485f]
0000000000428A29 E83280FFFF       call StrToCurr
0000000000428A2E 4889C1           mov rcx,rax
0000000000428A31 488B0510E80000   mov rax,[rel $0000e810]
0000000000428A38 48F7E9           imul rcx
0000000000428A3B C7C110270000     mov ecx,$00002710
0000000000428A41 48F7F9           idiv rcx
0000000000428A44 488BC8           mov rcx,rax
0000000000428A47 488B0502E80000   mov rax,[rel $0000e802]
0000000000428A4E 48F7E9           imul rcx
0000000000428A51 C7C110270000     mov ecx,$00002710
0000000000428A57 48F7F9           idiv rcx
0000000000428A5A 488905F7E70000   mov [rel $0000e7f7],rax
```

Note that the 32 bit code performs the arithmetic on the FPU, but the 64 bit code performs it using integer arithmetic. That's the key difference.

In the 32 bit code, the following calculation is performed:

- Convert '0.01' to currency, which is 100, allowing for the fixed point shift of 10,000.
- Load 14,500 into the FPU.
- Multiply by 100 giving 1,450,000.
- Multiply by 11,824,200 giving 17,145,090,000,000.
- Divide by 10,000^2 giving 171,450.9.
- Round to the nearest integer giving 171,451.
- Store that in your currency variable. Hence the result is 17.1451.

Now, in the 64 bit code, it's a little different. Because we use 64 bit integers all the way. It looks like this:

- Convert '0.01' to currency, which is 100.
- Multiply by 14,500 which is 1,450,000.
- Divide by 10,000 which is 145.
- Multiply by 11,824,200 giving 1,714,509,000.
- Divide by 10,000 which is 171,450. Uh-oh, loss of precision here.
- Store that in your currency variable. Hence the result is 17.145.

So the issue is that the 64 bit compiler divides by 10,000 at each intermediate step. Presumably to avoid overflow, much more likely in a 64 bit integer than a floating point register.

Were it to do the calculation like this:

```
100 * 14,500 * 11,824,200 / 10,000 / 10,000
```

it would get the right answer.

Comment: You should add how to prevent this: `currCalcValue := currGross * currPercent / 100;` will calculate the same result on both platforms. `*` will be calculated before `/`

Comment: @SirRufo That's just a sticking plaster. There is a fundamental weakness in the way the 64 bit compiler divides by 10,000 at every intermediate step. Try your solution on an expression with an extra multiplicative operand. Or even just different numbers.

Comment: Probably the compiler is trying to avoid overflowing in the advertised range (-922337203685477.5807 922337203685477.5807)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, I expect that's what it is doing. It doesn't seem to matter how they try to implement a decimal type, it sucks every time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It sounds like we aren't going to be able to work-around the issue. We could deal with the differences if clients were strictly going to be 64 bit but we're going to have a mix of 32/64 bit clients. We are running XE2. Might later versions have corrected this?

Comment: @JeffCope Nope. The x64 codegen has not really changed since XE2. Same behaviour in XE5. If I were working with decimal values, I'd roll my own data type using an advanced record with operator overloading. I'd start by looking at how .net implements its decimal type. Emba's `Currency` type sucks.

Comment: Yes, either switch to double or even http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.FmtBcd.TBcd or use http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools ...

Comment: FWIW, for a decimal type that works, try: http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html. I'll upload the version with 64 bit code added soon.

Comment: FYI...We worked with Embarcadero on this issue and they verified it was a problem with their compiler. This is supposed to be corrected in the next release of Delphi, XE6.

Comment: @JeffCope I dread to think how they will fix it. My guts tell me they will switch the 64 bit code gen to do all the work on the FPU. I'd be interested to find out. When you get the fix, if you leave a comment here, or tweet me (see my profile), I'd be keen to look at what they did.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed as of XE5u2 and as of current writing XE6u1.